# translate a variable amount of input values into a select

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var namelist = editnamebox.children.value;
for (var f = 0; f < namelist.length; f += 1) {
            slotname.innerHTML = '<optgroup><option>' + namelist[f] + '</option></optgroup>';
}
```

editnamebox is a `div` containing avariable number of `inputs` I want to generate a  with the value of each editnamebox input as an option.

The code above does no work, I also tried `namelist[f].value` instead of in the namelist var which also does not run. What is wrong here?

Full page: http://powerpoint.azurewebsites.net/
Set a timeslot. "Undefined" should be the content of the empty text fields above

Comment: Can you post your `div` sample with a few inputs ? Also what is `slotname` ?

Comment: What is the value in `namelist`? I suspect it's a string, in which case you will need to `.split()` it into an array. Second, you are overwriting the `.innerHTML` of `slotname` on each iteration of the loop. You need to create your elements and `.append` them to the parent.

Comment: added a link to my page. namelist is a list of <input>'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build the string with the loop and then update the innerHTML. (Assuming other portions are correct without seeing your markup)

```
var namelist = editnamebox.children,
    slotnameHtml = '';

//build html string
for (var f = 0; f < namelist.length; f += 1) {
     slotnameHtml += '<optgroup><option>' 
                       + namelist[f].value 
                       + '</option></optgroup>';
}

slotname.innerHTML = slotnameHtml; //update html
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the missing `+` sign. Generally these little things go un identified.

Comment: Seems to do more than before, I now have options. However they are "undefined". I updated the code: http://powerpoint.azurewebsites.net/ (set presenter names, then select time slots)